# Yii2 - Unique validator two attributes different models

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a model `Printer`, a model `Category`, and a model for the relation between the two models `CategoryPrinterRel`

In the `CategoryPrinterRel` model I need a unique validator between the `$category_id`, and the client of the printer `$printer->client_id`

Up till now I have tried

```
public function rules()  
{
    [['category_id', $this->printer->client_id], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['category_id']]
}
```

Is there any other way to do this though?
The problem with the method I'm using is that when the `printer` object is empty, trying `$this->printer->client_id` gives an error

Comment: The first item of your rules should be an array of attributes (their names in string form). `$this->printer->client_id` is a *value* (probably an integer?). That's never going to work.

Comment: I do have those rules, but I omitted them here for brevity. And it worked, but as I mentioned it's giving me errors when printer is empty

Comment: I'm trying to find an alternative way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for something more elegant, or built in. For now I have opted for a custom validator however. In the model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['category_id', 'printer_id'], 'integer'],
        [['printer_id', 'category_id'], 'required'],
        [['cat_id'],'validateUniquenessOnClient']
    ];
}

public function validateUniquenessOnClient($attribute, $params, $validator)
    {
        $isPrinterUniqueOnClient = DbPrinterRepository::IsPrinterCatRelUniqueOnClient($this->category_id, $this->printer_id);
        if(!$isPrinterGroupUniqueOnClient)
        {
            $this->addError($attribute, "There is already a printer using that category ({$this->cat->name}).");
        }

    }
```